# Adding and removing fragment with same button from framelayout

Tags: android, xml

I am new to android working first time on fragment.I am creating an app in which I want to add a fragment on frame layout.I am able to do this but now what I want is to remove the same fragment which i added by that same button click I tried but couldn't. here is my code.

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if(v.getId() == R.id.clickme){
        if(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.layout.fragment_one) != null){
          //  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.layout.fragment_one)).commit();
            Fragment fragment = new FragmenOne();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();

    }else{
            Fragment fragment = new FragmenOne();
         //   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.my_frame, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fullfill your requirement using boolean flag. When you add fragment make it to true.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do in this manner

```
Fragment f = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.my_frame);
        if(f instanceof FragmenOne) {
            FragmenOne oneFragment = (FragmenOne) f;
            FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
            trans.remove(oneFragment);
            trans.commit();
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
        }else{
            Fragment fragment = new FragmenOne();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.my_frame, fragment)
            .commit();
        }
```